# Swift NSManagedObject does not conform to protocol sequence Type

Tags: swift, image, relationship, nsmanagedobject

I have an `NSManagedObject` called `Media` which stores a picture and a description.

Here's the class and extension definition:

```
class Media: NSManagedObject{}

extension Media {

@NSManaged var desc: String?
@NSManaged var image: NSData?
@NSManaged var carRelationship: Car?

}
```

Swift stores the image without issue:

```
        myMedia = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Media", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! Media
        myMedia.image = NSData(data: UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1)!)
        car.mediaRelationship = myMedia
```

But when I go to retrieve it, the compiler complains: (doesn't compile)

```
       for pic in car.mediaRelationship {

    }
```

The error is:

> Type 'Media?' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence Type'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have `@NSManaged var mediaRelationship: NSSet?` in your car NSManagedObject. Don't forget to unwrap (if let) mediaRelationship when retrieve set.
Also check if inverse relationship is set